# BIND9 configuration, which allows DDNS updates and configuration-mgmt updates in the same time?

Tags: dns, bind, ansible, puppet, ddns

Not sure if it is possible at all, but I am trying to find solution for such setup:

- BIND9 server, managed by Puppet(https://github.com/ajjahn/puppet-dns), Puppet populates zone files for all static hosts
- except Puppet we have set of network devices, managed by Ansible, and there we would like to generate DNS records dynamically, and update DNS with nsupdate_module

I've find out what it is possible to update DDNS enabled zones using `rndc freeze`/`rndc thaw`, but my problem is, at the `thaw` step BIND9 doesn't want to use journal, it just shows such error:

```
journal file is out of date: removing journal file
```

I've found another option, `ixfr-from-differences`, but with that one, after `rndc thaw`, all dynamic changes disappears.

i.e. looks like such freeze/amend/thaw approach is working fine with manual changes, but doesn't fit with configuration-management pattern, as at the amend step, Puppet is recreating all static dns records from the catalog and trowing away ddns hosts.

So, maybe anyone see some more tricks, how to workaround such problem, or maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic zones in BIND are journalled (similarly to databases and filesystems): the updates do not immediately regenerate the actual zone file (which could be very time or I/O consuming operation for large zones); they are only appended to the .jnl file until some periodic sync happens.

If I remember correctly, in older BIND versions `rndc freeze` used to flush the journal automatically, but now it no longer does that – it only makes the server refuse *new* updates and doesn't do anything with those which have been already received into the journal but not yet flushed.

So you need to run `rndc sync -clean` after freezing, but before making your edits, in order to preserve all dynamic changes.

Comment: well, it still doesn't help much with my case, because the Puppet, in case of changes, regenerating a whole zone file anyway.
i.e.,  I was looking for some option, allows me to apply dynamic changes from the journal **after** rndc freeze/thaw actions on the zone file.